# Issues with EE On IIS with Directories

Tags: 404, iis

I moved my IIS site from a hosted server (Apache) to IIS. In doing so I

- Made the normal IIS install, installed PHp and mysql
- Copied all the files to wwwroot
- Added the database.

Now what happens is that i can get to the root mynewserver.com but if i click any links or type a link that has the subdirectory such as mynewserver.com/mypath i get 404 errors.

But mynewserver.com/system does work.

Another hint is that mynewserver.com/index.php/mypath totally works...

I'm guessing this has something to do with IIS looking for directories over the PHP paths? 
Or what config am i missing?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you have in your web.config file? You'll find this in the site's root. Are you using web.config to redirect all requests to your index.php file? If not, this might help:
http://www.climbingturn.co.uk/resources/expressionengine-tips-and-tricks/how-to-remove-index.php-on-iis

Comment: Yes, thats what i needed i had the .htaccess and needed to translate that to iis world.